# Подскажите правильную структуру state при использовании redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Товарищи, прошу помощи!

Возникла такая проблемка при формировании структуры редьюсеров и state в целом.

Возьмем, к примеру, добавление новости на сайт:
У новости есть данные непосредственные - заголовок, содержимое (контент), метаданные.

Но у новости также есть картинки, теги, категории.

Понятное дело, что на сайте помимо новостей будет еще куча сущностей.

И здесь встает вопрос - максимально разделять редьюсеры (news, uploads, categories, tags) и потом это все собирать в компоненте из разных частей, но зато все красиво и структурировано, или сделать редьюсер под новости и в него сразу включить все эти поля и не заморачиваться, собирая потом все из одной части стейта.

Подскажите как делают чаще. Как правильнее? С реактом и редаксом знаком совсем недавно, поэтому сложно как-то решить самому.

Comment: Вопрос этот возник из-за стремления к порядку и правильному проектированию , например как в базах данных. И вот стоит ли вообще эти вещи сравнивать по своей сути?

Comment: А ты попробуй всё расположить в одном поле - может тебе удобно будет. Мне, например, не удобно когда имеется глубокая вложенность.

Comment: я просто столкнулся еще с таким моментом, что если все собрано в одном редьюсере, то при обновлении стейта нет кучи перерендеринга компонента, а если я сначала обновил news, потом uploads, потом categories - ну это уже как минимум 3.

Comment: не представляю себе кейса, в котором разделение цельной сущности `news` на отдельные `text, uploads, categories, tags` имело бы смысл. Получили объект `newsItem` с этими полями, обновили стейт. Какой смысл разделять загрузку картинки и тескта на уровне глобального стейта?